# How can I get the output for form without the page changing

Tags: php, html

I am trying to get information from textarea to be converted to a .py file.
Here's my file https://jsfiddle.net/girlwhocancode/68mb49gq/

```
<form action=action.php method="post">
   <center>
     <textarea placeholder="Code you want to execute in python..."></textarea> 
   </center><br/>
   <center><input type="submit" class="button_example"></center>
</form>
```

and this is my php file:

```
<?php
 $path = #PATH;
 if (isset($_POST['field1'])) {
    $fh = fopen($path,"a+");
    $string = $_POST['field1'];
    fwrite($fh,$string); // Write information to the file
    fclose($fh); // Close the file
 }
?>
```

For some reason my php isn't working and I have no idea how to keep the same webpage after submitting

Comment: there is not `field1` in your code. why?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
   <center>
     <textarea name="script" placeholder="Code you want to execute in python..."></textarea> //added name
   </center><br/>
   <center><input name="submit" type="submit" class="button_example"></center>
</form> // added name submit
```

in php

```
<?php
 $path = #PATH;
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $fh = fopen($path,"a+");
    $string = $_POST['script'];
    fwrite($fh,$string); // Write information to the file
    fclose($fh); // Close the file
 }
?>
```

> Remember that in php $_POST/$_GET keys are always your form field
>   names

Comment: updated: <form action="action.php" method="post"> added double quotes in action

Comment: is action.php in same folder as your html file?

Comment: Do you have apache installed? Using wamp or xampp ?